# How to group some data on basis of two fields in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, group-by

Here I'm trying to keep **track** of my Employees **Skills** like when they are **added**, when **removed** and then **new skills are added**.

So, I'm getting storing them in the **database** as follows:

[image: Skills History Table]

Then **Retrieving** the data as follows:

```
$skillHistories = SkillsHistory::with('skills')->where('employees_id', $emp_id)->orderBy('date')->get();
```

And then **showing them in the blade** as:

```
@foreach ($skillHistories as $skillHis)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $loop->index + 1 }}</td>
    <td>
        <span class="badge rounded-pill bg-primary m-l-15">{{ $skillHis->skills->skill_name}}</span>
    </td>
    <td>{{ $skillHis->date }}</td>
    @if ($skillHis->status == 1)
        <td><span class="badge rounded-pill bg-success">Added</span></td>
    @else
        <td><span class="badge rounded-pill bg-danger">Removed</span></td>
    @endif
</tr>
@endforeach
```

So as expected in the browser **it shown like this**:

[image]

But I want to **group** all the **added skills on a date** and all the **removed skills** **on a date** in an **individual group**. And I want to **order** the list on **basis of date**.

Kind of as follows(This is static):

[image]

How can I Achieve that?
Thanks!

Comment: The Model Relations are as follows: From employee model:     public function skillHistory()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(SkillsHistory::class, 'employees_id', 'id');
    }   And from SkillsHistory model:     public function employee()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Employees::class, 'employees_id', 'id');
    }

    public function skills()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Skill::class, 'skill_id', 'id');
    }

Comment: Have you tried ```->groupBy('date', 'status')``` ?

Comment: Thanks man. This works. I tried implementing this in the model maybe that's why i was getting errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$skillHistories = SkillsHistory::with('skills')->where('employees_id', $emp_id)->orderBy('date')->get();
$array = [];
foreach ($skillHistories as $key => $skillsHis) {
    $array[$skillsHis->date]['date'] = $skillsHis->date;
    $array[$skillsHis->date]['skills'][] = $skillsHis->skills->skill_name;
    $array[$skillsHis->date]['status'] = $skillsHis->status;
}
$skills_array = array_values($array);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2022-10-01
        [skills] => Array
        (
            [0] => NP
            [1] => CL
            [2] => CM
            [3] => NAP
            [4] => NLM
        )
        [status] => 1
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [date] => 2022-10-04
        [skills] => Array
        (
            [0] => NP
        )
        [status] => 0
    )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the collection using map

```
$skillHistories =  SkillsHistory::with('skills')
           ->where('employees_id', $emp_id)
            ->orderBy('date')->get()
            ->groupBy(function ($item, $key) {
              $status = ($item->status == 1) ? 'Added' : 'Removed';
              return $item['date'].'_'.$status;
                            })
                            ->map(function ($group, $key) {
                               
                                $x['date'] = (explode('_', $key))[0];
                                $x['status'] = (explode('_', $key))[1];
                                $x['skills'] = $group;
                                return $x;
                            });
```